# Turn LED light on when I receive a new Skype alert?

Tags: windows, skype, instant-messaging, led

Is there a way to have one of the LED lights on my computer to light up when I get a new Skype message or alert?  I found this on Ubuntu, but would like to see this functionality in Windows...

Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Important detail: what led are you talking about?

Comment: Some laptops have dedicated LEDs to signal new email messages, for example.

Comment: Gnoupi: I think scroll lock will be awesome

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write a Skype plugin, which falls to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) to help you solve. If you are not a programmer, then maybe could you suggest it to programmers on forums like the [Skype community forums](http://forum.skype.com/).